# I have a problem entering the command npm audit fix --force

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

when entering a command npm audit fix --force I get an error

The error as it appears on the cmd is as follows:

```
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN audit Updating sqlite3 to 4.2.0,which is a SemVer major change.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\FluffyBot\node_modules\sqlite3
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! �믮������ ��᫥����⥫쭠� ᡮઠ �஥�⮢ � �⮬ �襭��. �⮡� ������� ��ࠫ������ ᡮ��, ������� ��ࠬ��� "/m".
npm ERR!   unpack_sqlite_dep
npm ERR!   "C:\Program" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
npm ERR!   ��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.
npm ERR! C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(209,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" �����訫��� � ����� 1. [C:\FluffyBot\node_modules\sqlite3\build\deps\action_before_build.vcxproj]   
npm ERR! Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=C:\FluffyBot\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v93-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\FluffyBot\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v93-win32-x64 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.11.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@16.6.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "C:\FluffyBot\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v93-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.2.0/node-v93-win32-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 403 https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.2.0/node-v93-win32-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(403): https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.2.0/node-v93-win32-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@4.2.0 and node@16.6.1 (node-v93 ABI, unknown) (falling back 
to source compile with node-gyp)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http 403 status code downloading tarball https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v4.2.0/node-v93-win32-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.6.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.6.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 2.7.18 found at "C:\Python27\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS using VS2017 (15.9.28307.1759) found at:
npm ERR! gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
npm ERR! (node:12452) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Python27\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',        
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\FluffyBot\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\ILYA\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\16.6.1\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\ILYA\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\16.6.1',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\ILYA\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\16.6.1\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\FluffyBot\\node_modules\\sqlite3',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\FluffyBot\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.6.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:394:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\FluffyBot\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\node-v93-win32-x64\\node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=C:\\FluffyBot\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\node-v93-win32-x64" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v93"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\FluffyBot\node_modules\sqlite3
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.6.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=C:\FluffyBot\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v93-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\FluffyBot\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v93-win32-x64 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\FluffyBot\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:394:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\FluffyBot\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\FluffyBot\node_modules\sqlite3
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.6.1
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
```

I tried using earlier and later versions but it didn't help.Could some one have a look at the error and let me know what steps I need to do to rectify this..

I am on node.js 16.6.1 and npm 7.20.3